# Does the Samsung Galaxy S2 support WPA2 with AES?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, wpa2

I'm trying to connect my Samsung Galaxy S2 to my TP-Link WA801ND Access Point. This works when I disable Wireless security but when I enable WPA2, the mobile refuses to connect.

Does the S2 support WPA2?

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but I would expect that the SGS2 supports WPA2 AES. Try an minimal example for the SSID and paraphrase without any fancy letters.

Comment: No game :-( My iPhone 4 also can't connect, so it's probably a bug in the WA801ND :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original SGS supports WPA2 with AES, so I would bet that the SGS2 does.  There seems to be a glut of routers that don't play nicely with non-PC devices when using WPA, for whatever reason, so I would suspect that's your issue.

Comment: Yes. My Galaxy S is also connected with WPA2 with AES...